# laravel 5.4 HTTP ERROR 500 unable to handle this request

Tags: laravel

I am uploading the `Laravel 5.4` project in a sub domain of `rehobothmissionschool.org` `Cpanel` its showing

> "This page isn’t working `rehobothmissionschool.org` is currently
>   unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

I changed the `PHP` version from `5.6` to `7.1` even that it's not working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkNcN.png)

Comment: Show your Laravel log in `storage\logs` ?

Comment: Is APP_DEBUG=false in env??

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true ......how i will show logs its too much line of code